# Google oAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch in token access

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, access-token

I am trying to access token from one-time code using Google oAuth2. But I am getting an error message `redirect_uri_mismatch` in the response. However i've already added the `redirect_uri` in console.

I have my `Authorized redirect uri` as:

```
http://localhost:3020/api/users/google_oauth_store_token
```

My request:

```
Request URL = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?code=xXXXxx&client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3020/api/users/google_oauth_store_token&grant_type=authorization_code
```

My response:

```
  response = {
    "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake. I had to use the `redirect_uri` that i had used in one-time redirect uri. Google uses one of the redirect_uri to rest the client origin.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your solution?

Comment: @tixastronauta Go to your Google Developers Console > Then go to API Manager > Click on the Credentials > Go to your Web Client Service. You'll see clientid and client secret. Below there somewhere you'll find Authorized redirect URI. Just add your redirect uri for eg. `www.example.com/oauth'. Now google will use one of the listed redirect uri. It will fix your problem. it worked for me. My mistake was i had added wrong redirect uri. :)

Comment: @CodeGeeky i'm hitting api call from postman but it always gives me same error

Comment: i added my url(subdomain url) in Authorized redirect URIs but still giving me same error.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set redirect_uri = "postmessage" ! That's it!

Comment: Spent hours and hours on this troubleshooting redirect_uri_mismatch hell