# Google OAUTH using django get access token

Tags: oauth, django-rest-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm struggling to retrieve access token using django.
I want to get access token from users using oAuth.

This is what I have setup so far.

```
class GoogleExhangeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()


    @list_route(
        methods=["GET"])

    def auth(self,request,pk=None):
        client_id = ''
        client_secret = ''
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=client_id,
                                   client_secret=client_secret,
                                   scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                                   redirect_uri='http://localhost:8001/api/googleAuth/complete')
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_uri)

     def complete(self, request, pk=None):
        client_id = ''
        client_secret = ''
        host = Site.objects.get_current().name
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=client_id,
                                   client_secret=client_secret,
                                   scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                                   redirect_uri='http://localhost')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(request.GET.get('code'))
        return Response(status=200,data=credentials.access_token)
```

under urls.py I have

```
api_router.register(r'api/googleAuth', GoogleExhangeViewSet)
```

This is the error I get with the following code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As seen in your error, you are encountering a `redirect_uri_mismatchBad Request` if you are using a wrong redirect uri. From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129281/error-redirect-uri-mismatch-google-api-oauth2-to-get-access-token), the redirect_uri_mismatch will be thrown if it was not matched between auth and token requests.

Additional references:

- [Google oAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch in token access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567419/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-mismatch-in-token-access)
- [Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224946/google-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-mismatch-error)

Here's a [tutorial](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html) if you want to use an [Access Token](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html#term-access-token) to authenticate users against Django’s authentication system.

You need a fully-functional OAuth2 provider which is able to release access tokens: just follow the steps in the [part 1 of the tutorial](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html). To enable OAuth2 token authentication you need a middleware that checks for tokens inside requests and a custom authentication backend which takes care of token verification.